# SQLAlchemy and Kubernetes - OperationalError 2013 - "Lost Connection to MYSQL server during query"

Tags: python, mysql, kubernetes, sqlalchemy, kops

### Problem

**Intermittent Operational Error 2013 - Lost connection during query**... many times a day and apart from that it behaves normally.

---

**Infra. Overview:**

We're using K8s cluster (created using kops) to deploy our applications but our primary DB server is not yet migrated to kubernetes which means it still resides in a separate EC2 instance outside kubernetes cluster.

We use Flask_SQLAlchemy to connect our flask app to MySQL.

I've created `mysql` service in my namespace with endpoint pointing to private IP of Mysql's EC2 instance.

---

As I know, similar questions related to OperationalError have been already asked and I've applied almost all of the fixes suggested.

- `sqlalchemy_pool_recycle = <way-less-than-servers-wait_timeout>` // 900 (mysql's is 28800)
- `sqlalchemy's` `pre_ping` is set to true
- kernel's `nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 3600`  (but pool will be recycled in 900)

---

- Flask_sqlAlchemy - v2.1
- SqlAlchemy - v1.3.12
- Flask - v0.11
- Kops - v.1.15.1
- kubernetes - 1.15.7
- Mysql - 8.x

---

**Please help me to understand it deeper. Suggestions welcomed.**

Answer (score -1):

its flask app config issue. you can update in app config below settings that should fix the issue.

```
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 50 # scale app for pool size # default 10

SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 250 # pool recycle time in seconds
```

Flask_sqlAlchemy has issue to close session , you need update in mysql config as well .

```
[mysql]
lock_wait_timeout=300
```

It should less than `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` as mentioned in flask documentation here :- https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#timeouts

"it is recommended that you set `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` to a value less than your backend’s timeout".

Comment: Hey @anish thanks for your answer but I've already mentioned in my question that my POOL_RECYCLE is much less than my MySQL's wait timeout. Regarding `lock_wait_timeout` I'll definitely give it a try. Thanks a lot again